# Is it legal to read a file descriptor into NULL?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

Recently, I've been [fixing the timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) for the sake of a library that I am writing. Following some research, suppose that I ended up with this prototype, precise and easy to combine with the generic event system of my library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <poll.h>

struct pollfd fds[1];
struct itimerspec its;

int main(void) {
    fds[0] = (struct pollfd) {timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0), POLLIN, 0}; //long live clarity
    its.it_interval = (struct timespec) {0, 16666667};
    its.it_value = (struct timespec) {0, 16666667};
    timerfd_settime(fds[0].fd, 0, &its, NULL);
    while(1) {
        poll(fds, 1, -1);
        if(fds[0].revents == POLLIN) {
            long long buffer;
            read(fds[0].fd, &buffer, 8);
            printf("ROFL\n");
        } else {
            printf("BOOM\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fds[0].fd);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it severely hurt me that I've had to pollute my CPU caches with a whole precious 8 bytes of data in order to make the timer's file descriptor reusable. Because of that, I've tried to replace the `read()` call with `lseek()`, as follows:

```
lseek(fds[0].fd, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Unfortunately, both that and even `lseek(fds[0].fd, 8, SEEK_CUR);` gave me `ESPIPE` errors and would not work. But then, I found out that the following actually did its job, despite of giving `EFAULT`s:

```
read(fds[0].fd, NULL, 8);
```

Is it legal, defined behavior to offset the file descriptor like this? If it is not (as the `EFAULT`s suggested to me, strongly enough to refrain from using that piece of genius), does there exist a function that would discard the read data, without ever writing it down, or otherwise offset my timer's file descriptor?

Comment: It is likely that the `read()` function (system call) will fail with `EINVAL` as the error, not actually reading anything.  No, you're not supposed to pass a null pointer to `read()` — but the kernel won't crash when you try.  It is a way to validate whether a pointer is valid — but it isn't fast.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't passed a null pointer and a count of 0, but a null pointer and a count of 8, and apparently it had actually offset these 8 bytes as a side effect... Is it by chance known to be slower than a normal read(), or just the normal, expected amount of slow?

Comment: Check the return value from the [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), and if it is negative, check the value in `errno`.  The pointer is invalid — you will most probably get a return value of `-1` and `errno == EINVAL`.  And no data will be read because there is nowhere valid to store it.

Comment: Of course the data will not be read into a place where I could read it, but assuming that it's exactly what I want to happen (only in a legal way), I'm pretty confident that [this](https://paste.awesom.eu/h5mv) timesteps properly (and as such, definitely offsets the file descriptor) everywhere I tried so far; had it not, the ROFLrotor would quickly overspeed, so to say :)

Comment: Interestingly, the POSIX specification doesn't document an error for an invalid buffer pointer (null pointer) — but you're not supposed to call functions with null pointers unless the behaviour is documents; you invoke _undefined behaviour_ when you do.  On macOS Mojave (1014.6), the man-page for `read()` documents the error _`[EFAULT]` — Buf points outside the allocated address space._ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX specification of [read(2)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) does not specify the consequences of passing a null pointer as the buffer argument. No specific error code is given, nor does it say whether any data will be read from the descriptor.

The [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) has this error, though:

> `EFAULT` *buf* is outside your accessible address space.

It doesn't say that it will read the 8 bytes and discard them when this happens, though.

So I don't think you can depend on this working as you desire.

Comment: Thank You for answering! Does there, by chance, exist something that I am unaware of, that could work closer to what I desire (i.e. increment the offset without reading anything), or is actually reading what the descriptor has to say the best bet here?

Comment: Not if the stream isn't seekable.